# Java: Non-static Communication. Ex: Type1 X; Type2 Y; X$\leftrightarrow$Y

Tags: java, static-analysis

I have two JFrame windows equipped with various components including JButtons and I want the actionPerformed methods for the buttons to send data between the two windows so that one can update the other. Thankfully, I've already got all the button code and everything figured out. The problem is when I try to send a signal String say, I have no name to reference because the windows are instances and all I have is the static class methods and such to work with. To illustrate my point, consider the following psuedo:
**Type1 X = new Type1();** //X is a window
...elsewhere...
**Type2 Y = new Type2();** //Y is a window
**Y.setVar( $\color{red}{\text{X}}$.getVar()); $\leftarrow$ Error**
X and Y are not local to eachother for referencing. So although I know they both exist, they do not. And calling anything in the class doesn't work for static reasons. Any ideas how to work around this non-static communication problem?

Update:
I have tried making their definitions local to each other (using a 3rd class) and I still get the same issue. My intuition says it needs to be like a "try catch" situation, where I wrap X in something that will catch the signal from the button...

Comment: This should probably go to regular Stackoverflow not CS. Anyways, you need something that is accessible to every window - consider something like a registry where a new window registers itself and which has some accessors. Alternatively, consider a message/event bus. Generally, your questions raises some red flags with me regarding your application's design/user interface - assuming it is a single application, multiple windows (not documents!) are almost universally a bad way to separate concerns.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Its a single application, but its like a user prompt thing I'm trying to do. Similar to how you would use Scanner for the Terminal Window to accept a String input or otherwise. Except I don't want the user interacting with the terminal window, so I made a different window with a data field and a button. When they input the String and click Enter its supposed to relay that String to the main window's instance variables for computation. I'll look into registries and message/event buses. Also maybe threading?

Comment: Most important advice when coding: Don't overcomplicate things! :)
Registries/buses/threading are all massive overkill for such a small application. Just subclass window and add a public method that you can call with the string later - keep a reference to the window after instantiating it where you can call it from your button's listener. Or even just keep references to all your components in your UI class - then you don't have to worry about other things.

Comment: I'll try implementing one as a subclass like you said. I kind of just opted out and used the Terminal Window/Scanner to get what I wanted. It just looks better with the separate window. I also tried putting "X.getVar()" in a do while (.equalsIgnoreCase("")) loop, but it ran infinitely and wouldn't spawn the window anymore. I also tried writing to a file and reading the file, since that is more or less static and you can edit the contents. But the same infinite loop problem happens when you are waiting to get the signal. I'm hopeful for the subclass attempt, will update

Comment: This is off-topic here. Perhaps migrate to [se].

Comment: He says go to Stackoverflow, you say Stack Exchange, which one is it? I posted to what I thought was Stack Exchange...